# How can I retreive or log the symmetric session key when using the 'ssl' library in python 3.x?

Tags: python, ssl, wireshark

I'm using Python 3 and want to use SSL for a client and server I am writing.

I would like to be able to debug what gets sent/received. Obviously, SSL prevents doing that with Wireshark, unless I can make Python use a non-perfect forward secrecy and give the server key to wireshark, or if I can [log the symmetric key generated for each session and save it in a file](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/).

I'd like to do that latter, as it should work with any of the ciphers used.

I should be able to handle the logging to a file part. But I'm not sure how to retrieve the symmetric key used in an TLS session with the Python 'ssl' library. How do I go about retrieving those keys (preferably server side, but I could do it in the client if necessary)?

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution to this? I am facing a similar issue where I need the TLS session keys after creating an SSL socket between a client and a server. Thank you!

Comment: @DhruvRauthan No, I didn't. Obviously, I've long since found what I was doing wrong on this particular project, but an answer would still be very useful for other projects. Sorry I don't have anything to share!